# activate a python virtualenv from makefile

Tags: python, makefile, virtualenv

i would like to use a Makefile command to activate a python virtual env.
My Makefile looks something like this:

```
activate:
      . ./.ven/bin/activate
```

However when i run "make activate" nothing happen to my shell. 
This is probably due to the fact that make use his own shell to activate the venv.

Is it possible to call make activate and affect my current shell (bash).

Thanks

Comment: A child process cannot modify the environment of a parent process. This means that nothing in a `Makefile` will be able to affect your current shell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+makefile